# Is there a way to redraw Bokeh charts?

Tags: python, bokeh

I have 2 charts in Bokeh and an input box. The input box takes a value and should update both charts. I have a function called `createDF` that creates a DF and then calls `createPlot` which returns back a figure to `createDF` and then `createDF` calls `createDF2` which calls `createPlot2` and then returns a figure back to `createDF`. Now we have 2 figures in `createDF`, we bundle this into a list and return back and then displays the charts like so:

```
plot = createDF(market)
l = layout([[text_input], [plot[0]], [plot[1]]])
curdoc().add_root(l)
```

This is how I'm trying to handle the update:

```
def text_handler(attr, old, new):
    market = text_input.value
    plot = createDF(market)

    l = layout([[text_input], [plot[0]], [plot[1]]])
    curdoc().add_root(l)
text_input.on_change('value', text_handler)
```

However, whenever I input a different market, the charts don't update. How can I make them update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just two possible details you should check:

Are you running bokeh in server mode? This is required as you are using a python callback function (text_handler)

https://docs.bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html

Another possible problem: you are creating new figure objects in your callback function instead of manipulating the already existing objects.

Have a look at one of the bokeh gallery examples:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/movies/main.py

A plot and a glyph is created:

```
p = figure(plot_height=600, plot_width=700, title="", toolbar_location=None, tooltips=TOOLTIPS)
p.circle(x="x", y="y", source=source, size=7, color="color", line_color=None, fill_alpha="alpha")
```

And afterwards, in the update function they modify the existing instances:

```
def update():
    df = select_movies()
    x_name = axis_map[x_axis.value]
    y_name = axis_map[y_axis.value]

    p.xaxis.axis_label = x_axis.value
    p.yaxis.axis_label = y_axis.value
    p.title.text = "%d movies selected" % len(df)
    source.data = dict(
        x=df[x_name],
        y=df[y_name],
        color=df["color"],
        title=df["Title"],
        year=df["Year"],
        revenue=df["revenue"],
        alpha=df["alpha"],
    )
```

If you keep a reference to the glyph object:

```
my_glyph = p.circle(x="x", y="y", source=source, size=7, color="color", line_color=None, fill_alpha="alpha")
```

You could later on (in the callback function) change for example the series (column) of the data source where the values should come from or the size:

```
my_glyph.y = 'other_column_name'
my_glyph.size = 42
```

Comment: Yes i am running the server, i think youre right i am creating new figures. How do i update the existing ones?

Comment: I added a link to the bokeh examples gallery and some code snippets from there.